# I accidentally boiled away most of my soup, what can I do to recover it?

Tags: soup

I wanted to reheat my chicken tortilla soup and walked away and forgot about it. When I went back to the stove very little liquid was left in the pot, it was practically all boiled away.

I used a Mexican tortilla soup stock by Swanson. Other ingredients in this recipe are black beans, corn, diced tomatoes, onions, jalapenos and tomato paste, plus the chicken. This is the only Mexican recipe that I make.

What should I do?

- What would happen if I poured in 3 cans of water for example? What would happen to the flavor of the soup?
- If I add preheated water will the water dilute the flavor?
- Do I just put in 1 cup/can or can I put in 3 cups/cans of water?

Comment: Reheating it all over again to get the flavour into the water will overcook everything else to mush. You should start again, and eat the failed leftovers as burritos or enchiladas as you suggested.

Comment: Seems like you've lost your account - normally, you should be able to edit and comment on your own question regardless of reputation points, but since you're unregistered and probably changed computers or closed your browser, you've accidentally created a different unregistered/temporary account. Consider registering a permanent account and then [contacting the team](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/contact) for an account merge, to get the edit/comment functionality back.

Comment: You're lucky that you didn't boil it away completely ... then you end up burning things and have a pot that's a pain to clean.

Answer (score 3):

If you add preheated water, you don't need to reheat the soup--just mix in and enjoy!  Depending on how strong it is, you could also just eat it as-is--IMHO the best soups always reduce the stock anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with James - a few cups of hot water will do fine.